# HTTP response code to throttle google search appliance bot (gsa)

Tags: http-headers, web-crawler, google-search-appliance, throttling, http-response-codes

What HTTP response code should be used to throttle a badly behaved web crawler:

- [403 Forbidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)
- [503 Service Unavailable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)

Should any explanation be returned in the headers or in the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the recommended([RFC6585](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585)) http status is [429 Too Many Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#page-3). It is used, for example, on [Twitter REST API Rate Limiter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1).

However, GSA will internally [return 503 Service Unavailable](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/60/troubleshooting/Designing_Search_Solution#Queueing) if you [flood it with requests](https://support.google.com/gsa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2686272), so IMO it's a safe assumption that it also expects external sites to behave in the same manner.

I went with [503 Service Unavailable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) on my throttling solution.